# Access list of data in the Master Page code behind to front end of the same master page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm loading some of data to a list called "TransactionNames" in the code behind of the master page (TestMaster.Master).
Now I need to pass that list of data to front-end of the master page(TestMaster.Master) using java script. 
I tried like above,

[image]

Comment: Please do not paste code as an image, but as plain text. It's easier for others to copy the code for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `List` in code behind that is declared outside a method:

```
public List<string> TransactionNames = new List<string>();
```

Then you need to create an array in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var TransactionNames = ["<%= string.Join("\",\"", TransactionNames) %>"];

    //or

    var TransactionNames = <%= "['" + string.Join("','", TransactionNames) + "']" %>;

    for (var i = 0; i < TransactionNames.length; i++) {
        alert(TransactionNames[i]);
    }
</script>
```

Or it becomes even easier when you use `Newtonsoft.Json` to serialize objects:

```
var TransactionNames = <%= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TransactionNames) %>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do using declare global public variable:

Code Behind:

```
public string[] TransactionNames=new string[]
    {
        "schnauzer",
        "shih tzu",
        "shar pei",
        "russian spaniel"
    };
```

Source File:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var TransactionNames= <%= TransactionNames %>;
    for(var i=0; i < TransactionNames.length;i++){
       var tx=TransactionNames[i];
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention exactly what do you want to do with the transaction names on the front-end of master page e.g. adding them to a menu, concatenating them to a label etc or creating a

structure from the names;

Suppose you want to create a

structure; here is the code

```
for(i =0;i< TransactionNames.length;i++)
            {
                $("#ul").append("<li>" + TransactionNames[i] + "</li>");
            }
```